# How to click on the button with text as public as per the HTML through Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

```
 <div class="actionButton-container row">
                        <input type="hidden" name="addComment" value="TES-2" id="addCommentTES-2"/>
                          <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <!-- RESET BUTTON -->
                            <!-- button type="submit" class="btn blue changeBtn" id="Add" type="submit">Add</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn white changeBtn" id="cancel">Cancel</button> -->



                            <button class="btn blue changeBtn" id="public" onclick="addCommentsForUser()" type="button">Public</button>
                              <button class="btn blue changeBtn" id="inner" onclick="addCommentsForUser()" type="button">Inner</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn white changeBtn" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
                          </div>

                      </div>
```

Above it is the HTML code. I try to use to the code below to get the button in selenium and perform a click. it say that the element not found.

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("actionButton-container")).FindElement(By.Id("public")).Click();
```

or

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("public")).Click();
```

Anyone know the solution for this?

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: @AnkurSingh no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"public"}

Comment: Can you share url ? Check whether it's inside any frame or not

Comment: So sorry Can't share the url as it is located in a private server

Comment: IMO, there are 5 such buttons, which button do you want to click?

Comment: @DebanjanB public button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='commentSFHD-12']")).SendKeys("TEST Function");
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
  IWebElement ibtn3 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("public"));
  IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
  executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", ibtn3);
```

By using the code above it works correctly now

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this, as your are not sharing URL it is hard to find conclusion. But try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Time));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element));
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Time));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
```

Comment: tried it still have error message: element not visible

Comment: You use javascriptExecutor?

Comment: Also check is element in Frame?

Comment: Yes I use IJavaScriptExecutor. what Frame you mean? iFrame or some other frame?

Comment: it does not consist of any iframe

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the button with text as **Public** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='actionButton-container row']//button[@class='btn blue changeBtn' and @id='public']"))).Click();
```

Comment: tried the above solution but it is not working. Error message :OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 10 seconds
Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 10 seconds
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element

Comment: _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _ExpectedConditions_. Debug your code through  `findElement()` inconjunction with `Thread.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.

Comment: I try to do use this method to debug:-
 IList<IWebElement> attachmentList = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='comment-containerTES-2']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div"));
            foreach (var element in attachmentList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element.Text);
          
            }

the output was Public Inner Cancel

how to get the Public button from it